# Facebook API group posting single image error (#120) Invalid album id when caption includes a question mark (?)

Tags: facebook, photo, group

[image: facebook api group posting single image error (#120) Invalid album id when caption include ?]

Facebook API group posting single image error (#120) Invalid album id when caption includes a question mark (?) (with user token)

[image: with page token]
when uses page token error is "An unknown error has occurred."

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/739380653703276/?join_id=f2c83de4185cff8
Bug reported on Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug from Facebook and also reported
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/739380653703276/?join_id=f2c83de4185cff8